Why does the pages specified not load in the background on my website when specified to do so?
Question
I am trying to preload multiple pages in the background for a mobile web application that will run inside Safari WebView as well as Android WebView. However, despite creating two versions of my preload script, the pages still take time to load when visited. The script is also designed to check the user's internet connection speed and will only preload if the connection is adequate. If the connection isn't fast enough, preloading won't execute. Can someone provide insights or modifications to make the preloading work effectively?
Code Attempts
First Version:
{
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Preload Example</title>
    <script>
        function checkConnectionAndPreload(urls) {
            const connection = navigator.connection || navigator.mozConnection || navigator.webkitConnection;
            if (connection) {
                if ((connection.effectiveType.includes('4g') || connection.type === 'wifi') && connection.downlink > 2) {
                    preloadPages(urls);
                } else {
                    console.log('Connection is not suitable for preloading content.');
                }
            }
        }

        function preloadPages(urls) {
            urls.forEach(url => {
                fetch(url).then(response => {
                    if (response.status === 200) {
                        console.log(`Preloaded ${url}`);
                    }
                }).catch(error => {
                    console.error(`Failed to preload ${url}:`, error);
                });
            });
        }

        document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
            const urlsToPreload = ['https://examplewebsite.com/page1', 'https://examplewebsite.com/page2'];
            checkConnectionAndPreload(urlsToPreload);
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>

}
Second Version:
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Preload Example</title>
    <link rel="preload" href="https://examplewebsite.com/page1" as="document">
    <link rel="preload" href="https://examplewebsite.com/page2" as="document">
    <script>
        function checkConnectionForPreload() {
            const connection = navigator.connection || navigator.mozConnection || navigator.webkitConnection;
            if (connection) {
                if (!(connection.effectiveType.includes('4g') || connection.type === 'wifi') || connection.downlink < 2) {
                    console.log('Connection is not suitable for preloading content.');
                    removePreloads();
                }
            }
        }

        function removePreloads() {
            const preloadLinks = document.querySelectorAll('link[rel="preload"]');
            preloadLinks.forEach(link => {
                link.parentNode.removeChild(link);
            });
        }

        document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
            checkConnectionForPreload();
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>

Additional Information
I also attempted to preload a specific URL in the background on a button click using jQuery:
<body>
    <button id="buttonEnroll">Enroll</button>
    <div id="result"></div>

    <script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $("#buttonEnroll").on('click', function(e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                $("#result").load("https://examplewebsite.com/page1", function(response, status, xhr) {
                    if (status == "error") {
                        alert(`Failed to load page: ${xhr.status} ${xhr.statusText}`);
                    } else {
                        alert("Page loading completed");
                    }
                });
            });
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>

None of the above methods have successfully reduced loading times. I don't have any error logs or debug outputs to guide me, so I'm turning to the community for advanced insights into potential issues or mistakes in my scripts. Any help would be appreciated!

What have you tried to resolve the problem? Where are you stuck? Are you sure this problem is in any way related to PHP itself?

As far as I can tell your “preload” is just making a bunch of fetch calls, nothing else. Am I right? There’s no client-side cache, and you aren’t intercepting user clicks for these pages to redirect/handle with your cached versions. For the URLs that you are calling this way, what are the browser cache directives set to?

Thank you, Nico and Chris, for your insightful feedback. Based on your suggestions, I have revised my approach to include a service worker for better management of caching and to address the issues with client-side resource handling. Below is the updated version of my script, which now uses a service worker to cache the preloaded pages and serves them as needed.
Updated HTML and Service Worker Script:
index.html

I tried to paste in the script that I created but unfortunately I'm not able to do so because of stack overflow's character limit. I'm afraid to answer this question because this might be incorrect but I'm going to answer it anyway. Please let me know if this will fix the problem of the cache not being handled
